# Error while calling stored procedure from Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, plsql, spring-data-jpa

I tried several different ways to access to my stored procedure via my spring boot application but I have always Errors like :

> InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

or

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I tried :

```
 StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME");
        procedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("paramOut", Object.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        procedureQuery.execute();
        procedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue("paramOut");

@Transactional
@Procedure(procedureName= "MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME" )
Object getNextNumber();

@Query(value = "{call MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME()}", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
Object getNextNumber();
```

but always  it seems he can't reach my stored procedure in my DB : 
I added grand grant execute on ... to ... but that doesn't solve the problem

any idea, please

Comment: How did you create the procedure? If you - by any chance - used **double quotes**, then you must call it using double quotes, specifying letter case exactly as they were during CREATE PROCEDURE command.

Comment: @Littlefoot, this is the signature of my PLSQL procedure  `create or replace PROCEDURE MY_SHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE_NAME(
    paramout OUT NUMBER)`

Comment: @Littlefoot, this is the signature of my PLSQL procedure  `create or replace PROCEDURE MY_SHEMA.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME(
    paramout OUT NUMBER)`

Comment: Then double quotes aren't the problem. Are you connected as the owner of the procedure? If not, and - saying that you *granted privileges* - see whether preceding procedure's name with its owner name helps, i.e. `call my_schema.my_stored_procedure_name`.

Comment: I have now an error like this `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored I have not IN param I have only one OUT param

Comment: I have now this error when calling the stored procedure by the java code : `ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session`

Comment: The first error means that you have to provide *something* (I don't speak Java so I don't know it, but - in Oracle, it is usually a variable) that will accept value of the OUT parameter. The second error means that you have to remove COMMIT from where you have it now and, do it elsewhere.

Comment: Have you declared the stored procedure as describe here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-stored-procedures#1-the-car-entity

If you do, I think the second and possibly the first approach should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response 
So I resolved the bug related to call the stored procedure by preceding procedure's name with its owner name :

> `my_schema.my_stored_procedure_name`

and use

> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ...

inside the stored procedure

java code

`StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery 
 entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("my_schema.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME");

```
procedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("in1", Long.class, 
ParameterMode.IN);

procedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("in2", String.class, 
ParameterMode.IN);
procedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("out1", Long.class, 
ParameterMode.OUT);

 procedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("out2", String.class, 
 ParameterMode.OUT);

        procedureQuery.setParameter("in1", val1);
        procedureQuery.setParameter("in2", val2);
        procedureQuery.execute();
        procedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue("out1");
        procedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue("out2");`
```